# PC to Android USB streaming data using OTG USB - How?

Tags: java, android, usb, usb-otg

I am trying to accomplish communication between PC Java Application and an Android Application as shown in the diagram.

[image: PC to Android USB communication]

I want to be able to send streams of Strings from PC JAVA app to Android Application (Android studio). 
How can this be accomplished using OTG USB and direct communication (COM port) (I know it can be done over TCP and also using ADB protocol, but I am looking for something else, directly using USB/OTG).

Any suggestions/references ?

Answer (score 0):

> you have use this application

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.dvkr.screenstream&hl=en_IN

> this application code also avelable on Github

https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream